# Angular JS - ng-model, ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Добрый день! 
Есть вывод в цикле

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<p>{{ item.title }}</p>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxmodel" ng-change="checkboxmodel==1? func1(item) : func2(item)" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" />
</div>
```

Т.е. для каждого item должен быть свой чекбокс. Его значение не содержится в item, а вычисляется дополнительно. С checked/unchecked все работает, функции `func1(item), func2(item)` отрабатывают. Но как выставить первоначальное значение чекбоксу? Сейчас модель одна для всех чекбоксов, и нет возможности выставить значение у конкретного чекбокса через `$scope.checkboxmodel`

Пытаюсь сделать через массивы:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<p>{{ item.title }}</p>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="ItemsCtrl.checkboxes[$index]" ng-change="ItemsCtrl.checkboxes[$index]==1? func1(item) : func2(item)" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" />
</div>
```

В контроллере ItemsCtrl, где добавляются items, добавил:

```
$scope.checkboxes = [];
```

Затем пытаюсь добавить новый элемент - чекбокс со значением 1:

```
$scope.checkboxes.push(1);
```

Но, конечно, не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так должно работать:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <p>{{ item.title }}</p>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxes[$index]" ng-change="checkboxes[$index]==1? func1(item) : func2(item)" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" />
</div>
```

т.е. $scope контроллера должен быть доступен без специального указания контроллера.

Но вместо `ng-change` лучше использовать вотчер в контроллере, иначе не забудьте расшарить в `$scope` `func1` и `func2`

Comment: спасибо большое, так заработало.

Comment: поясните, пожалуйста, по поводу расшаривания func1 и func2

Comment: Предположим, моя func1(item) в контроллере ItemsCtrl выглядит так: $scope.func1 = function(item){ ... }. Как мне ее вызвать теперь из ng-change?

Comment: `$scope` - область видимости шаблона, если вы используете какие-либо функции, определённые в контроллере, их надо сделать свойствами `$scope`, если это ещё не сделано, аналогично как вы делаете с `items`, т.е. $scope.func1 = function () ...

Comment: функции как раз сейчас у меня как свойства $scope

Comment: все, спасибо огромное, заработало, глюк какой-то был, видимо))